# Which Python package/library is best for this kind of game?

Tags: gui, python

I'm wanting to make a small scale version of the game Hearthstone and other 2d games that I can implement self-learning ai in. I was wondering which python GUI would be best to display them. It would need buttons and the ability to place images in specific locations in the GUI.